# IdHTTP Get Response Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, idhttp

How use thread for this code, this code makes the program take a quick locked in thread would be better?

how to repeat the thread until i = ListBox1.Items.Count -1

```
 var
    lURL : String;
    lResponse : TStringStream;
begin
    lResponse := TStringStream.Create('');
    TestText := Form1.ListBox1.Items[i];
    I := i +1;
    Test1 := Copy(TestText, 0, 16);
    Test2 := Copy(TestText, 18, 3);
    Test3 := Copy(TestText, 22, 2);
    Test4 := Copy(TestText, 27, 2);
 try
     lURL := 'http://www.test.net/test/test.php' +
  '?n=' + Test1 +
  '&m=' + Test2 +
  '&a=' + Test3 +
  '&cv=' + Test4;
     idHttp1.Get(lURL, lResponse);
     lResponse.Position := 0;
     RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromStream(lResponse);
 finally
     IdHTTP1.Free;
     lResponse.Free();
     if Pos('Bazinga',RichEdit1.Text)> 0 then
     label1.Caption := 'True';
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Here's a good example: [Working with Indy HTTP](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+IV+Delphi+the+Internet+and+a+.NET+Preview/Chapter+19+Internet+Programming+Sockets+and+Indy/Working+with+HTTP/).  The code is for Dephi7 - your mileage may vary depending on your version.

Comment: [Wait for thread without freezing the application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908253/wait-for-thread-without-freezing-the-application)

Comment: Which Delphi version do you use?

Comment: I'm currently using Delphi XE6, also like to know how to repeat the thread as soon as it is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can individuate downloading code in a separate function, for example:

```
function DownloadString(AUrl: string): string;
var
  LHttp: TIdHttp;
begin
  LHttp := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    LHttp.HandleRedirects := true;
    result := LHttp.Get(AUrl);
  finally
    LHttp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Then use an Anonymous thread to fetch the content:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LUrlArray: TArray<String>;
begin

  // Your URLs are stored in an array of strings
  LUrlArray := form1.listbox1.Items.ToStringArray;

  // This will start an anonymous thread to download the string content from the list of URLs
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      LResult: string;
      LUrl: string;
    begin
      // Fetch each site content from the URL list
      for LUrl in LUrlArray do
      begin
        // DownloadString will be executed asynchronously
        LResult := DownloadString(LUrl);

        // Safely update the GUI using TThread.Synchronize or TThread.Queue
        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            // Add the resultant string to ???
            // Decide where to set the text to
            memo1.Lines.Text := memo1.Lines.Text + LResult;
          end
        );
      end;
    end
  ).Start;

end;
```

**Pay special attention to the GUI update part!**

> The same could be done with ITask if you were using Delphi XE7.

***Note 1:*** This works fine for small content payload. If you download huge content or file it's better to use a TStream descendant.

***Note 2:*** In this case only one thread will download all URL's content

Comment: how to repeat the thread until i = ListBox1.Items.Count -1?
im using
      TestText := Form1.ListBox1.Items[i];
      I := i +1;
      Test1 := Copy(TestText, 0, 16);
      Test2 := Copy(TestText, 18, 3);
      Test3 := Copy(TestText, 22, 2);
      Test4 := Copy(TestText, 27, 2);

Comment: You didn't mention there is a listbox? Please, update your question first.

Comment: DownloadString WILL BLOCK THE GUI until the function exists!

Comment: @SolarWind - yes, but the second example shows using a thread to overcome GUI thread blocking.

Comment: @iPathツ- Sorry, I don't understand. If I use the second example (the one with Synchronize) the GUI won't freeze, even if EACH download size is let's say 300MB?

Comment: @SolarWind in the second example DownloadString() is called within the context of an anonymous thread so it runs autonomously from the GUI thread. Only the result is shown within the context of the main (GUI) thread.

Comment: Oh... Right. You mean: "TThread.CreateAnonymousThread". Many thanks for clarification. +1