# With C++Builder, how to run AniIndicator along whith WaitFor() in main thread?

Tags: multithreading, firemonkey, c++builder

Following [this Delphi sample](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/5289-tlistview-filled-by-thread-freeze/) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908253/), I built three scenarios in order to run properly `TAniIndicator` along with `WaitFor()` in the main thread.

In the first two tests, I use the `Synchronize()` and `Queue()` methods with `FreeOnTerminate=false/FreeAndNil()`. In the third test, I got rid of the `WaitFor()` without success. In all cases, the app freezes with message:

> Project1 isn't responding. Do you want to close it ? Wait/OK

Note that in the third scenario, the `TAniIndicator` spun correctly if the variable `PHONENumber` is assigned before the execution of the REST request. Curiously, after this line, the app freezes again. This would be my preferred solution.

Below is my code:

**.h**

```
// ...
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TAlphaThread : public TThread
{private:
 protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();
 public:
    __fastcall TAlphaThread(bool CreateSuspended);
    //void __fastcall OnTerminate(TObject *Sender); Never triggered
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//===========================================================================
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TBetaThread : public TThread
{private:
 protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();
 public:
    __fastcall TBetaThread(bool CreateSuspended);
    //void __fastcall OnTerminate(TObject *Sender); Never triggered
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//===========================================================================
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TDeltaThread : public TThread
{private:
 protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();
 public:
    __fastcall TDeltaThread(bool CreateSuspended);
    //void __fastcall OnTerminate(TObject *Sender); Never triggered
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//===========================================================================
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // Composants gérés par l'EDI
//  ...
private:    // Déclarations utilisateur
public:     // Déclarations utilisateur
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);

    UnicodeString PHONENumber; // Mobile number

    TRESTClient *REST1Client;
    TRESTRequest *REST1Request;
    TRESTResponse *REST1Response;
    TAlphaThread *AlphaThread;
    void __fastcall AlphaThreadTerminated(TObject *Sender);

    TRESTClient *REST2Client;
    TRESTRequest *REST2Request;
    TRESTResponse *REST2Response;
    TBetaThread *BetaThread;
    void __fastcall BetaThreadTerminated(TObject *Sender);

    TRESTClient *REST3Client;
    TRESTRequest *REST3Request;
    TRESTResponse *REST3Response;
    TDeltaThread *DeltaThread;
    void __fastcall DeltaThreadTerminated(TObject *Sender);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//...
```

**.cpp**

```
//...
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{//
 REST1Client = new TRESTClient(this);
 REST1Request = new TRESTRequest(this);
 REST1Response = new TRESTResponse(this);

 REST2Client = new TRESTClient(this);
 REST2Request = new TRESTRequest(this);
 REST2Response = new TRESTResponse(this);

 REST3Client = new TRESTClient(this);
 REST3Request = new TRESTRequest(this);
 REST3Response = new TRESTResponse(this);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//===========================================================================
// Scenario 1 => Project1 isn't responding. Do you want to close it ? Wait/OK
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Tap(TObject *Sender, const TPointF &Point)
{//
 PHONENumber = NULL;
 AlphaThread = new TAlphaThread(true);
 AlphaThread->OnTerminate = &AlphaThreadTerminated;
 AlphaThread->Start();

 if(AlphaThread->WaitFor())
  {if(PHONENumber == NULL) ShowMessage(L"Null value!"); else Label1->Text =  PHONENumber;
  }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::AlphaThreadTerminated(TObject * Sender)
{//
 FreeAndNil(Form1->AlphaThread);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TAlphaThread::TAlphaThread(bool CreateSuspended) : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{//
 FreeOnTerminate = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* Never triggered
void __fastcall TAlphaThread::OnTerminate(TObject * Sender)
{ShowMessage(L"TAlphaThread::OnTerminate!");
 FreeAndNil(Form1->AlphaThread);
}*/
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TAlphaThread::Execute()
{//
 Synchronize([this](){
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Align = TAlignLayout::Contents;
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Enabled = true;
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Visible = true;
  }
 );

 // Chargement des données
 Form1->REST1Client->BaseURL = "my.URL.php";
 Form1->REST1Request->AddParameter("ID", "123");
 Form1->REST1Request->Client = Form1->REST1Client;
 Form1->REST1Request->Response = Form1->REST1Response;
 Form1->REST1Response->ContentType = "application/json";
 Form1->REST1Request->Execute();

 // Assignation des variables
 TJSONValue *JV0TOPLevel; JV0TOPLevel = Form1->REST1Response->JSONValue;
 TJSONArray *JSONArray = dynamic_cast<TJSONArray*>(JV0TOPLevel);
 TJSONObject *JSONObject = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>(JSONArray->Items[0]);
 TJSONValue *JV0ITEMLevel;

 JV0ITEMLevel = JSONObject->GetValue("FIELDName"); Form1->PHONENumber = JV0ITEMLevel->AsType<String>();

 Synchronize([this](){
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Enabled = false;
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Visible = false;
  }
 );

 ReturnValue = 1;
 Terminate();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//===========================================================================
// Scenario 2 => Project1 isn't responding. Do you want to close it ? Wait/OK
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Tap(TObject *Sender, const TPointF &Point)
{//
 PHONENumber = NULL;
 BetaThread = new TBetaThread(true);
 BetaThread->OnTerminate = &BetaThreadTerminated;
 BetaThread->Start();

 if(BetaThread->WaitFor())
  {if(PHONENumber == NULL) ShowMessage(L"Null value!"); else Label2->Text =  PHONENumber;
  }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BetaThreadTerminated(TObject * Sender)
{//
 FreeAndNil(Form1->BetaThread);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TBetaThread::TBetaThread(bool CreateSuspended)
    : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{//
 FreeOnTerminate = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
void __fastcall TBetaThread::OnTerminate(TObject * Sender)
{// Never triggered
 ShowMessage(L"TBetaThread::OnTerminate!");
 FreeAndNil(Form1->BetaThread);
}*/
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TBetaThread::Execute()
{//
 Queue(NULL, [this](){
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Align = TAlignLayout::Contents;
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Enabled = true;
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Visible = true;
  }
 );

 // Chargement des données
 Form1->REST2Client->BaseURL = "my.URL.php";
 Form1->REST2Request->AddParameter("ID", "123");
 Form1->REST2Request->Client = Form1->REST2Client;
 Form1->REST2Request->Response = Form1->REST2Response;
 Form1->REST2Response->ContentType = "application/json";
 Form1->REST2Request->Execute();

 // Assignation des variables
 TJSONValue *JV0TOPLevel; JV0TOPLevel = Form1->REST2Response->JSONValue;
 TJSONArray *JSONArray = dynamic_cast<TJSONArray*>(JV0TOPLevel);
 TJSONObject *JSONObject = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>(JSONArray->Items[0]);
 TJSONValue *JV0ITEMLevel;

 JV0ITEMLevel = JSONObject->GetValue("FIELDName"); Form1->PHONENumber = JV0ITEMLevel->AsType<String>();

 Queue(NULL, [this](){
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Enabled = false;
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Visible = false;
  }
 );

 ReturnValue = 1;
 Terminate();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//===========================================================================
// Scenario 3 => Project1 isn't responding. Do you want to close it ? Wait/OK
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Tap(TObject *Sender, const TPointF &Point)
{//
 PHONENumber = NULL;
 DeltaThread = new TDeltaThread(true);
 /*DeltaThread->OnTerminate = &DeltaThreadTerminated;*/
 DeltaThread->Start();

 while(PHONENumber == NULL) {
  [this]()->String{return PHONENumber;};
 }
 if(PHONENumber == NULL) ShowMessage(L"Null value!"); else Label3->Text =  PHONENumber;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::DeltaThreadTerminated(TObject * Sender)
{//
 FreeAndNil(Form1->DeltaThread);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TDeltaThread::TDeltaThread(bool CreateSuspended)
    : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{//
 FreeOnTerminate = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* //Never triggered
void __fastcall TDeltaThread::OnTerminate(TObject * Sender)
{//ShowMessage(L"OnTerminate!");
 //FreeAndNil(Form1->DeltaThread);
} */
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TDeltaThread::Execute()
{//
 //Form1->PHONENumber = 123; Working!!

 Queue(NULL, [this](){
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Align = TAlignLayout::Contents;
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Enabled = true;
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Visible = true;
  }
 );

 //Form1->PHONENumber = 123; Working!!

 // Chargement des données
 Form1->REST3Client->BaseURL = "my.URL.php";
 Form1->REST3Request->AddParameter("ID", "123");
 Form1->REST3Request->Client = Form1->REST3Client;
 Form1->REST3Request->Response = Form1->REST3Response;
 Form1->REST3Response->ContentType = "application/json";
 Form1->REST3Request->Execute();

 // Form1->PHONENumber = 123; Freezing

 // Assignation des variables
 TJSONValue *JV0TOPLevel; JV0TOPLevel = Form1->REST3Response->JSONValue;
 TJSONArray *JSONArray = dynamic_cast<TJSONArray*>(JV0TOPLevel);
 TJSONObject *JSONObject = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>(JSONArray->Items[0]);
 TJSONValue *JV0ITEMLevel;

 JV0ITEMLevel = JSONObject->GetValue("FIELDName"); Form1->PHONENumber = JV0ITEMLevel->AsType<String>(); // Freezing

 Queue(NULL, [this](){
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Enabled = false;
   Form1->AniIndicator1->Visible = false;
  }
 );

 ReturnValue = 1;
 Terminate();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea of what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario 1:

- `TThread::WaitFor()` is blocking the main UI thread until the thread finishes running.  `WaitFor()` does not process new GUI messages while waiting, but it does process pending `Synchronize()` and `Queue()` requests (and does dispatch cross-thread messages sent with `SendMessage...()` to avoid deadlocks).
- you can't free the thread object from inside of its `OnTerminated` event handler. The RTL still needs access to the thread object after the handler exits.  If you want the thread to free itself, set its `FreeOnTerminate` property to `true` instead.  However, in this scenario, since you are waiting on the thread, you could just free the thread after `WaitFor()` exits instead.

A better way to handle this scenario is to update the `TAniIndicator` directly in `Button1Tap()` and get rid of the `OnTerminate` event handler altogether.  The `TAniIndicator` logic doesn't really belong in the thread's `Execute()` method to begin with.  However, you will have to manually pump the main thread's message queue for new messages while waiting for the thread to finish.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Tap(TObject *Sender, const TPointF &Point)
{
 PHONENumber = _D("");

 AlphaThread = new TAlphaThread(false);

 AniIndicator1->Align = TAlignLayout::Contents;
 AniIndicator1->Enabled = true;
 AniIndicator1->Visible = true;

 HANDLE h = (HANDLE) AlphaThread->Handle;
 while (MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &h, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT) == (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1))
 {
  Application->ProcessMessages();
 }

 int result = AlphaThread->WaitFor();
 delete AlphaThread;

 AniIndicator1->Enabled = false;
 AniIndicator1->Visible = false;

 if (result)
 {
  if(PHONENumber == _D(""))
   ShowMessage(_D("Null value!"));
  else
   Label1->Text = PHONENumber;
 }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TAlphaThread::TAlphaThread(bool CreateSuspended) : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{
 FreeOnTerminate = false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TAlphaThread::Execute()
{
 // Chargement des données
 Form1->REST1Client->BaseURL = _D("my.URL.php");
 Form1->REST1Request->AddParameter(_D("ID"), _D("123"));
 Form1->REST1Request->Client = Form1->REST1Client;
 Form1->REST1Request->Response = Form1->REST1Response;
 Form1->REST1Response->ContentType = _D("application/json");
 Form1->REST1Request->Execute();

 // Assignation des variables
 TJSONValue *JV0TOPLevel = Form1->REST1Response->JSONValue;
 TJSONArray *JSONArray = static_cast<TJSONArray*>(JV0TOPLevel);
 TJSONObject *JSONObject = static_cast<TJSONObject*>(JSONArray->Items[0]);
 TJSONValue *JV0ITEMLevel = JSONObject->GetValue(_D("FIELDName"));
 Form1->PHONENumber = JV0ITEMLevel->AsType<String>();

 ReturnValue = 1;
}
```

However, in this scenario, there is really no point whatsoever in having the main thread create a worker thread just to block itself waiting on that thread.  You may as well just perform the REST logic directly in the main thread instead.  You can use the REST components *asynchronously* to avoid blocking the main thread (ie, by using `TRESTRequest::ExecuteAsync()` instead of `TRESTRequest::Execute()`).

---

Scenario 2:

- all of the same issues as Scenario 1.

---

Scenario 3:

- there is no call to `TThread::WaitFor()` in the main thread, so the `Queue()` requests go unprocessed, but at least they won't block the worker thread from running.  That would not be the case had you used `Synchronize()` instead.
- the `while` loop in the main thread is creating a new lambda on each iteration, but is not actually *calling* the lambda.  This is just a busy loop that eats up CPU cycles for no gain.
- same issue with freeing the thread as the other scenarios.

---

Now, with all of that said, the *correct* way to handle this situation using a worker thread is to not wait on the thread at all. Let it run normally, and let it notify the main thread when finished. DO NOT block the main thread at all in the meantime.

Try this:

```
class TGetPhoneNumberThread : public TThread
{
 protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();
 public:
    __fastcall TGetPhoneNumberThread(bool CreateSuspended);
    String PHONENumber;
};
```

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Tap(TObject *Sender, const TPointF &Point)
{
 TGetPhoneNumberThread *Thread = new TGetPhoneNumberThread(true);
 Thread->OnTerminate = &GetPhoneNumberThreadTerminated;
 Thread->Start();

 Button1->Enabled = false;
 AniIndicator1->Align = TAlignLayout::Contents;
 AniIndicator1->Enabled = true;
 AniIndicator1->Visible = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::GetPhoneNumberThreadTerminated(TObject *Sender)
{
 AniIndicator1->Enabled = false;
 AniIndicator1->Visible = false;
 Button1->Enabled = true;

 TGetPhoneNumberThread *Thread = static_cast<TGetPhoneNumberThread*>(Sender);

 if (Thread->FatalException)
   ShowMessage(_D("Error! ") + static_cast<Exception*>(Thread->FatalException)->Message);

 else if (Thread->PHONENumber == _D(""))
   ShowMessage(_D("Null value!"));

 else
   Label1->Text = Thread->PHONENumber;
 }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TGetPhoneNumberThread::TGetPhoneNumberThread(bool CreateSuspended) : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{
 FreeOnTerminate = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <memory>
void __fastcall TGetPhoneNumberThread::Execute()
{
 std::unique_ptr<TRESTClient> RESTClient(new TRESTClient(NULL));
 std::unique_ptr<TRESTRequest> RESTRequest(new TRESTRequest(NULL));
 std::unique_ptr<TRESTResponse> RESTResponse(new TRESTResponse(NULL));

 // Chargement des données
 RESTClient->BaseURL = _D("my.URL.php");
 RESTRequest->AddParameter(_D("ID"), _D("123"));
 RESTRequest->Client = RESTClient.get();
 RESTRequest->Response = RESTResponse.get();
 RESTResponse->ContentType = _D("application/json");
 RESTRequest->Execute();

 // Assignation des variables
 TJSONValue *JV0TOPLevel = RESTResponse->JSONValue;
 TJSONArray *JSONArray = static_cast<TJSONArray*>(JV0TOPLevel);
 TJSONObject *JSONObject = static_cast<TJSONObject*>(JSONArray->Items[0]);
 TJSONValue *JV0ITEMLevel = JSONObject->GetValue(_D("FIELDName"));

 PHONENumber = JV0ITEMLevel->AsType<String>();
}
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of the worker thread completely and use `TRESTRequest` asynchronously instead:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Tap(TObject *Sender, const TPointF &Point)
{
 // Chargement des données
 REST1Client->BaseURL = _D("my.URL.php");
 REST1Request->AddParameter(_D("ID"), _D("123"));
 REST1Request->Client = REST1Client;
 REST1Request->Response = REST1Response;
 REST1Response->ContentType = _D("application/json");

 REST1Request->ExecuteAsync(
  [this](){
    // Assignation des variables
    TJSONValue *JV0TOPLevel = REST1Response->JSONValue;
    TJSONArray *JSONArray = static_cast<TJSONArray*>(JV0TOPLevel);
    TJSONObject *JSONObject = static_cast<TJSONObject*>(JSONArray->Items[0]);
    TJSONValue *JV0ITEMLevel = JSONObject->GetValue(_D("FIELDName"));

    PHONENumber = JV0ITEMLevel->AsType<String>();

    TThread::Queue(nullptr,
     [this](){
      AniIndicator1->Enabled = false;
      AniIndicator1->Visible = false;
      Button1->Enabled = true;

      if (PHONENumber == _D(""))
        ShowMessage(_D("Null value!"));
      else
        Label1->Text = PHONENumber;
     }
    );
   }
  },
  false
 );

 Button1->Enabled = false;
 AniIndicator1->Align = TAlignLayout::Contents;
 AniIndicator1->Enabled = true;
 AniIndicator1->Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: your code is working fine. Thank you so much. 
I renamed the class as `TGammaThread` in order it matches the constructor and I declared `GammaThreadTerminated()`, instead of `GetPhoneNumberThreadTerminated()`, as public function in TForm1.
Many thanks to all.

Comment: `TGammaThread` was a typo. Clearly, you missed the update where I fixed that